# Android component

Tags: android-layout

Does anyone know what component it is or what components are being used?:

Here is the link, it is the second image in the App Screenshots section:

[The Image](http://tinyurl.com/bfmdy9w)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` is used in that screen and with `custom Array Adaptor` and also `Button` controls are also used to navigate between days.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html

try this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/) if you want to learn about different layout used in android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you happen to know if those input controls are all in one layout or different layouts added into one layout? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends on you. how you want to create it. if you want that all the components are will be in separate layout and add that layouts in the master layout you can do that or you will just create one layout with different child layout in it that has components.

Comment: Oh OK, because I tried using a ListView, and I had a hard time trying to get it to work, especially with the programmes that start on different times. I will try again and see how I go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yeah, will do that now. Thanks.

Comment: you can also approve that if you find what you want.

Comment: Sorry I can't, it says I require 15 reputation.

Comment: Yeah, just approved it, Thanks.

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask, do you think that the Image is also in the ListView item? Because when the user scrolls the ListView to the left the images don't move they stay in the same place?

Comment: no than they are in the other layout i think he place the images in linear layout with vertical orientation. when you go through the link that I give you for the layout you will get the all basic idea of layout.